# Slow SVF Conversion

Tags: file-conversion, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We are utilizing Forge API for converting DWG to SVF for manipulation on mobile AutoDesk viewer. Our success in conversation sits at about 80% of the files converting correctly and relatively quickly. We often get either a failed conversation or ones that take upwards of 30 minutes. Obviously not optimal for client to wait that long to view / edit their drawing on iPad.

Are these additional error returns we can get so we can find the cause of these slow and failed DWG conversations?

Is there a FAQ of issues that commonly cause failure or long conversations. I believe we'd looked at external references.

Yes, we have looked through other StackOverflow related questions with little progress.

Comment: I edited your question to add better tags. Please tag your Autodesk Forge questions with the appropriate tags so we can more easily spot them. Autodesk Forge tags are documented here - https://developer.autodesk.com/en/support/get-help. As a minimum, please include the autodesk-forge tag.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, we may need a sample file to check out what is actually going wrong with the translation, without that, it's difficulty for us to tell the reason with the current information. The translation time is dependent on many different situation, usually, when it's a big/complicated file, or it has many external references may take time, but just as I mentioned, without a sample file to check, we can not give you conclusion. You can send to us personal if anything is sensitive.

For the error information, I think you should be already aware of, after post a translation job by [POST job](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/), you can get the status by [GET :urn/manifest](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/), and you can check the status to know how the translation goes. That should be the only way to check the progress as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Zhong. Please find the sample file at [link](https://numedia.box.com/s/51qme89axqbjxyltwubi8v1zzbp08cct). Understood on the POST & GET for status retrieval. Does Autodesk keep stats on success rates? I.e. If our DWG opens in AutoCAD, is it reasonable to expect it should convert in Forge? Also, we are still on trial membership, once we finish trial and go to paid subscription, should we expect an decrease in conversion times (i.e. Do paid subscribers get priority over trial users?) Thanks for the assistance!!

Comment: Hey Zhong, sorry to ask again, but wanted to see if there was any progress or feedback on the sample project posted above? Thanks!! Chuck

Comment: Sorry, I was traveling and in a training last week, I got your file, will try it and let you know the progress ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Zhong - - - hope your travels were successful! I'll await your evaluation of the file posted. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with very slow translation times is due to the complexity of the graphics in your DWGs. The sample DWG you sent me has exploded hatches used to indicate wall. That makes for a lot of data to be processed. (Because DWG is a highly compressed format, there isn't a particularly strong correlation between DWG size and translation time).

Try breaking the model up into separate DWGs for each floor plan / detail view - you should see a significant speed increase and avoid any timeouts. Maybe also use an xref for the common building structural model. The EXPORTLAYOUT AutoCAD command can be used from the original DWG with the layouts to make separate DWGs with just the specific layout data.

It might be possible to use the Design Automation API to automate pre-processing your DWGs before translating them.

Comment: Thanks Stephen - - -we're looking at the preprocessing options. Our long term challenge is that we don't directly control the DWGs that are provided to us. So we'd be looking to write scripts that would identify those items that cause delays and maybe throwing up warnings to the reps that are using our tool and notifying them .. . ultimately being able to handle some of those in an automated fashion would be the holy grail.